# Scheme Lambda? What is it?

Tags: scheme, racket, mit-scheme

What is it in scheme? How can we use it ?

```
scm> (define (x) 100)
x
scm> (x)
100
scm> x ; When we "called" x, it return (lambda () 100). what is it ?
(lambda () 100)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(define (x) 100)` is the same as:

```scm
(define x          ; define the variable named x
        (lambda () ; as a anoymous function with zero arguments
          100))    ; that returns 100

x   ; ==> #<function> (some representation of the evaluated lambda object, there is no standard way)
(x) ; ==> 100 (The result of calling the function)
```

You might be more in to Algol languages so here is the same in JavaScript:

`function x () { return 100; }` is the same as:

```js
var x =          // define the variable named x
  function () {  // as the anonymous function with zero arguments
    return 100;  // that returns 100
  };
x;   // => function () { return 100; } (prints its source)
x(); // => 100 (the result of calling the function)
```

Beginners sometimes add parentheses around variables like `((x))` and it is equivalent to writing `x()()` in Algol languages. Thus `x` must be a function of zero arguments that will return a function of zero arguments in order to work.

Answer (score 0):

`(define (x) 100)` is equivalent to `(define x (lambda () 100))`.
The first syntax is actually a syntactic sugar of the second. Both define a procedure.

When you use `x`, the Scheme interpreter will return you `x` itself. In this case, `x` is a lambda expression.
When you use `(x)`, you are calling a procedure named `x`. The scheme interpreter will **apply** what's inside `x`, in this case, a lambda expression, and return you the return value.

To use lambda, consider lambda expression as an operator.
So `((lambda (<arg-list>) <body>) <parameter-list>)`
Or, if you define a lambda expression to a variable, take the variable as the operator, for example, as what you do,

```
(define x
    (lambda () 100))
(x)
```